# attempting to remove discard mount option

Tags: fstab

Im trying to remove the discard option from /system (/dev/block/sde21)

when attempting this command

tune2fs -o^discard /dev/block/sde21

returns "Invalid mount option set: ^discard"

is there another way to remove the discard option?

any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Remount with:

```
sudo mount -oremount,nodiscard /system
```